# How can I make css Scrollable horizontal div with two row?

Tags: css

I want to make this UI (two rows)
every elements has own width and scrollable
[image]

and I found some ways like this link
https://codesandbox.io/s/flex-horizontal-scroll-with-wrap-max-2-rows-d7zj3m?file=/src/App.js:77-84

but I want to make the order is

[image]
How can I make this ui with css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Overflow-x" is to scroll div horizontally but won't work without "no wrap"

```css
.container{
  background: lightblue;
  width: 30%;
  height:50px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap; 
 
}
button{
  margin: 2px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>HTML Tutorial</title>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <br>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
    <button>CSS</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

but If you need to print odd and even numbers instead,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <style>
    .container {
      background: lightblue;
      width: 100px;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    
    p {
      margin: 5px;
    }
  </style>

  <div class=container>

    <p class="special"></p>
    <p class="first"></p>
    <p class="second"></p>
    <p class="special1"></p>

  </div>

  <script>
    function print() {

      var i;
      var special = document.getElementsByClassName("special")[0];
      var write = document.getElementsByClassName("first")[0];
      var write1 = document.getElementsByClassName("second")[0];
      var special1 = document.getElementsByClassName("special1")[0];

      for (i = 1; i <= 62; i++) {

        special.innerHTML += ' - ';
      }

      for (i = 1; i <= 60; i++) {
        if ((i % 2) == 0) {
          continue; //if num is odd, skip it. 
        }
        write.innerHTML += i + ' ';
      }

      for (i = 2; i <= 60; i++) {
        if ((i % 2) == 1) {
          continue; //if num is odd, skip it. 
        }
        write1.innerHTML += i + ' ';
      }
      for (i = 1; i <= 62; i++) {

        special1.innerHTML += ' - ';
      }

    }

    print(); //invoke print function
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is there any way to change the order like 1 3 5 | 2 4 6?

Comment: if I understood correctly, you want to replace "CSS" buttons with "number" texts?

Comment: Please check the answer again, I added a second solution based on what I think you need.